# Scrapy can't see a list

Tags: python, list, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl a specific page of a website (https://www.johnlewis.com/jaeger-wool-check-knit-shift-dress-navy-check/p3767291) to get used to Scrapy and its features.  However, I can't get Scrapy to see the 'li' that contains the thumbnail images on the carousel.  My `parse` Function currently looks as follows:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for item in response.css('li.thumbnail-slide'):
        #The for loop works for li.size-small-item
       print("We have a match!")
```

No matter what Scrapy isn't "seeing" the li.  I've tried viewing the page in a scrapy shell to check Scrapy could see the images and they are showing up in the response for that (so I'm assuming Scrapy can definitely see the list/images in the list).  I've tried alternative lists and I've got a different list to work (as per the comment in the code).
My only thoughts are that the carousel may be loaded with JavaScript / AJAX but I can't be too sure.  I do know that the list class will change if it is the selected image from "li.thumbnail-slide" to "li.thumbnail-slide thumbnail-slide-active" however, I've tried the following in my script to no avail:

1. li.thumbnail-slide
2. li.thumbnail-slide-active
3. li.thumbnail-slide.thumbnail-slide-active
4. li.thumbnail-slide thumbnail-slide-active

Nothing works.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?  Or suggest any further reading that may help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assumption is correct, the elements are there, but not exactly where you think they are.

To easily check if an element is part of the response html and not being loaded by javascript I normally recommend using a [browser plugin to disable javascript](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toggle-javascript/cidlcjdalomndpeagkjpnefhljffbnlo?hl=en).

If you want the images, they are still part of the html response, you can get them with:

```
response.css('li.product-images__item')
```

the main image appears separately:

```
response.css('meta[itemprop=image]::attr(content)')
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Yeah that works!  Disabling JavaScript showed the images right at the bottom of the page and the appropriate class they were under.  Thanks for your help